# Forward declarations for variables?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, struct, forward-declaration

I have some C code that I have to port to C++. The code has a structure

```
struct A { 
    ...
    struct A * myPtr;
}
```

And now two global arrays are declared and initialized like this:

```
//Forward declaration of Unit
struct A Unit[10];

struct A* ptrUnit[2] = { Unit, Unit+7 };
struct A Unit[10] = { { .., &ptrUnit[0] }, 
                      ... };
```

Now while this works fine in C, it gives an error in C++ (variable redeclared).
Aren't variables allowed to be forward-declared in C++?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In C++, a variable *declaration* must be prefixed with `extern`:

```
extern A Unit[10];

// ...

A Unit[10] = { ... };
```

(Note that in C++ you can omit the leading `struct`.)

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration/1410632#1410632) for more details on declarations and definitions.

Comment: your statement about `the same namespace` is not completely correct. A `struct A` definition has an implicit `typedef struct A A` as a consequence, if the identifier `A` is not defined in the same scope. Something like `struct A { ... } A;` is completely legal in C++, and then `A` (without `struct`) refers to the object. That this is possible, doesn't meant that this is good style, though. In POSIX you have that for example with the "sys/stat.h" header file that defines `struct stat` and the function `stat`.

Comment: @Jens: I'm not sure on the legal details of this, but you seem to have a point. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt: They still live in different identifier spaces, and there is no implicit `typedef` (else the symbol would also be defined in the global identifier space). The difference between C and C++ here is that if a symbol is not located in the identifier space, it will also be looked up in the user defined types. There is a slightly longer explanation in this answer I wrote some time ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675351/typedef-struct-vs-struct-definitions/1675446#1675446

Comment: @David: thanks for the pointer. The rule for C++ is even worse than I thought.

Answer (score 26):

`struct A Unit[10]` is not a forward declaration of a variable. The term "forward declaration" normally refers to *non-defining* declarations, while `struct A Unit[10]` is a *definition*. So in your code you are defining `Unit` multiple times in the same source file. In C language it is allowed, since in C definitions without an initializer are *tentative definitions*. They may occur many times in the same translation unit. In C++ there's no such thing as tentative definition. In C++ multiple definitions are always illegal.

If you want a genuine forward declaration for a variable, you have to use the keyword `extern`

```
extern struct A Unit[10];
```

This will work in both C and C++. However, as a side effect, this will give `Unit` *external* linkage. If you need a variable with *internal* linkage, then you are out of luck in C++, since in C++ it is not possible to forward-declare a variable with internal linkage. Meanwhile, in C tentative definitions will still help you to achieve that.

Comment: For internal linkage in С++ you can use something like this: `namespace { extern struct A Unit[10]; }`. I guess it is not really internal linkage, but `Unit` will be available only in the current translation unit anyway. https://stackoverflow.com/a/15419573/5447906

Answer (score 1):

[C allows](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/data_dec.htm) variables to be tenatively declared (I guess). C++ does not. Once 'Unit' has been defined, it cannot be redefined in the same scope

Answer (score 0):

Make `Unit` a function that returns a reference to to A[10] and have the actual array be a static variable in the function.

```cpp
// in hpp file
A[10]& Unit();

// in cpp file
A[10]& Unit() {
    static A[10] value;
    return value;
}
```