# C++ - How do you pass a variable from one form to another?

Tags: c++, windows, forms

I have a Form1.h and a Form2.h

Form1.h is already including Form2.h because i start Form2 by clicking a button in Form1. So how would i pass a variable from Form1.h to Form2.h

Here is an example of Form1.h

```
#include "Form2.h"

String^ str = "Hello World"; //This variable needs to be passed to Form2.h

//Other windows forms application code here
```

An example of Form2.h

```
//#include "Form1.h" this will cause an error

//How would i pass variable str to here?

//Other windows forms application code here
```

Edit:

This is how i fixed it

This is how i fixed it.

Form1.h

```
#include "Form1.h"

Form2^ frm = gcnew Form2;
frm->Username = "text here";//This passes the variables.
frm->Password = "other text";
```

Form2.h

```
public: String^ Username;
public: String^ Password;
```

Comment: In order to help you, we're going to need to see your code that you are having an issue with.

Comment: Including Form1.h in Form2.h and accessing directly? Form2 is a variable and you were able to access variable Form2 by means of including Form2.h in Form1.h. It works both ways ;)

Comment: @The_aLiEn actually. It just gives me an error because you can't have 2 files including eachother i guess.

Comment: Let me guess, "Circular Unit Reference" ?

Comment: Idk what that is but it's not working when i include Form1.h to Form2.h :\

Comment: Make the form's constructor take a reference to the other form (it can be replaced with a specific variable if that's the only one you need to change).

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: @The_aLiEn Visual Studios 2010, chris i didn't even understand that.

Comment: I dont have Visual C++ installed in my VS, I'm using Embarcadero RAD Studio for my visual C++ work.. Anyways, language is language; you should have that worked. Try including form1.h in form2 code area, this is unit2.cpp for my rad std, file name can be different with vs

Comment: Since no one has mentioned it, you can forward declare it.

Comment: @The_aLiEn I already tried that and it gives me C4430 errors.

Comment: @FreelanceCoder, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/c-forward-declaration

Comment: @FreelanceCoder http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714808/forward-declarations-for-variables

Comment: None of this stuff makes sense to me :|

Comment: Any help? I'm still really lost here.

Comment: This is how i fixed it.

Form1.h

    #include "Form1.h"
    
    Form2^ frm = gcnew Form2;
    frm->Username = "text here";//This passes the variables.
    frm->Password = "other text";

Form2.h

    public: String^ Username;
    public: String^ Password;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure what your asking, but im assuming that you want to set a variable in *Form2* class from inside *Form1* class? If so:

```
class Form1{
  private:
    int data;
  public:
    Form1(){data=4;}
    int getData(){return data;}  //returns Form1 data variable
    void setForm2Data(Form2&);   //sets Form2 data
};

class Form2{
  private:
    int data;
  public:
    void setData(int inData){data = inData;}
};

void Form1::setForm2Data(Form2 &o){
  o->setData(getData());  //argument is a Form2 object, "setData" can set that objects data variable
}
```

Comment: Nope. I already have Form2.h included in Form1.h, I need to pass a variable to Form2 from Form1 without including Form1.h inside Form2.h

Comment: ah i see. you want something called a "static" function then, check back in 5 mins while i edit my comment

Comment: Btw, Form1 and Form2 aren't classes. They are Forms as in Windows Forms Applcations. They also use the .NET Framework.

Comment: ohh k, you shouldv'e specified that in the question briefly (even with the tag, the question kinda looked like a normal C++ header file question). Unfortunately, can't really help you there then.

Comment: @FreelanceCoder You're mentioning .Net now... Is it a Windows Application Visual C# or Windows Application Visual C++ ?

Comment: @The_aLien Windows Form Application Visual C++

Comment: Is anyone still trying to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

You get an error because your preprocessor directives cause double inclusion.
To avoid this you can use pragma guards

Form1.h:

```
#ifndef FORM1_H
   #define FORM1_H
   #include "Form2.h"
   extern string str = "Hello World";
#endif
```

Form2.h:

```
#include "Form1.h"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways.. one is to use global variables (not necessarily the best way.. depends per case basis)

First, you can solve the multiple inclusion problem by using [include guard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).

Then you can declare a global variable using extern keyword in the header, and plug in the value in the implementation file.

For example:

```
//file: mylib.h
#ifndef MYLIB_H
#define MYLIB_H
extern int myGlobalVar;
#endif

//file: mylib.cpp
#include "mylib.h"
int myGlobalVar = 123;
```

Now you can `#include "mylib.h"` anywhere in other file as many time as you like and access the same variable